# jqgrid url not invoking controller action method mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

i want to call a controller action from my jqgrid and for that i used url property of jqgrid, but still the controller action method is not being called....the jqgrid is being loaded but without any data, posting my view, can anyone point out where a i going wrong

```
<link href="../../Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




     $(document).ready(function () {

     var updateDialog = {

     url: "/Contact/Update"
            , closeAfterAdd: true
            , closeAfterEdit: true
            , afterShowForm: function (formId) {
                $("#PhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");
                $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker();
            }
            , afterclickPgButtons: function (whichbutton, formid, rowid) {
                $("#PhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");
            }
            , modal: true

            , onclickSubmit: function (params) {
                var ajaxData = {};

                var list = $("#list");
                var selectedRow = list.getGridParam("selrow");
                rowData = list.getRowData(selectedRow);
                ajaxData = { ContactId: rowData.ContactId };

                return ajaxData;
            }

            , width: "400"
     };
     $.jgrid.nav.addtext = "Add";
     $.jgrid.nav.edittext = "Edit";
     $.jgrid.nav.deltext = "Delete";
     $.jgrid.edit.addCaption = "Add Contact";
     $.jgrid.edit.editCaption = "Edit Contact";
     $.jgrid.del.caption = "Delete Contact";
     $.jgrid.del.msg = "Delete selected Contact?";
     $("#list").jqGrid({
         url: "/List/Contact/",
         datatype: 'json',
         mtype: 'GET',
         colNames: ['ContactId', 'Name', 'Date of Birth', 'E-mail', 'Phone Number', 'Married'],
         colModel: [
                { name: 'ContactId', index: 'ContactId', width: 40, align: 'left', /* key: true,*/editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }, hidedlg: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 300, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
                { name: 'DateOfBirth', index: 'DateOfBirth', width: 200, align: 'left', formatter: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true, date: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 200, align: 'left', formatter: 'mail', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true, email: true }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
                { name: 'PhoneNumber', index: 'PhoneNumber', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: isValidPhone }, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *'} },
                { name: 'IsMarried', index: 'IsMarried', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, editrules: { required: true}}],
         pager: $('#listPager'),
         rowNum: 1000,
         rowList: [1000],
         sortname: 'ContactId',
         sortorder: "desc",
         viewrecords: true,
         imgpath: '/Content/Themes/Redmond/Images',
         caption: 'Contact List',
         autowidth: true,
         ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
             $("#list").editGridRow(rowid, prmGridDialog);
         }
     }).navGrid('#listPager',
            {
                edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true
            },
            updateDialog,
            updateDialog,
            updateDialog
        );
 });       
</script>

//My Action Method 
public ActionResult Update(ContactViewModel viewModel, FormCollection formCollection)
{
 return Content(repository.HasErrors.ToString().ToLower()); 

}
```

Comment: Include the action method used as the jqgrid URL in your question.

Comment: And also try setting a break point on that action and check whether the control reaches that point.